# how get increase or decrease value from event listener

Tags: javascript, html, events, listener

How can I check if input number increase or decrease with listener?

I take a look in the whole EVENT, am not find a property or method that shows if the input has increased or decreased.

I know I can get the step from `event.target.step`, but I need to see the increase value to look if it increase or decrease.

I don't want to add a new global variable to my scope.

My target is to made a ratio lock button.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    dataIntepretor.oninput = function(event){ // click on a input
        console.log('event: ', event);
        const element = event.target;
        const numberPad = event.data;
        const value = element.value;
        const key = element.id;
        const key2 = element.attributes.id2 && element.attributes.id2.value; //array id
        asignSessionValue(session,key,value,key2);
        if(element.attributes.id2){// if is a array props, look for ratioLock
            const lock = document.getElementById(`${key}_lock`).checked;
            if(lock){
                asignSessionValue(session,key,Number(element.step),~~!key2,true);
                //const element2 = document.querySelectorAll(`#${key}`)[~~!key2];
            }
        }
        refresSpriteSession(objSprite,session);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you will need to create a new variable whose value will be overwritten each time an event is fired, something like this:

```
var previousValue = 0; // Let's set the initial value to 0

document.getElementById("myInput").oninput = function()
{
    // You can do something at this moment if you want

    if(this.value > previousValue)
    {
        // Value has been increased
    }
    else
    {
        // Value has been decreased
    }

    previousValue = this.value;
}
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to create a global variable then perhaps you can set your own property on that input object which will be tied to that input object only and when each time an event is fired then instead of updating that global variable's value, you can simply update the value of that custom property. You could refer to that property by using `this.propertyName` or `event.target.propertyName` whenever an event is fired. Let me show you how to do it:

```
var inputField = document.getElementById("myInput");

inputField.previousValue = 0;

inputField.oninput = function()
{
    // You can do something at this moment if you want

    if(this.value > this.previousValue)
    {
        // Value has been increased
    }
    else
    {
        // Value has been decreased
    }

    this.previousValue = this.value;
}
```

I hope this helps you. Let me know in the comments please :)

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the `readonly` attribute on the ratio inputs attached with the lock button. User cannot change the value of read-only input until you remove it.

Update: here is a living example: http://jsfiddle.net/0n2Lerae/3/

Comment: am not shure i understand , can you give me more code and explain ?

Comment: @jon I've updated my answer with an example on fiddle

Comment: @HankPhung Why use 5 lines of code when instead you could do it with only 1 line? http://jsfiddle.net/0n2Lerae/6/

Comment: @Zahid: Clear code will be easy for anyone to read and understand.